# RecyclerView and a view collapsed on tap causes RecyclerView to "jump" on scroll

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` which has children that expand on tap. I also have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` at the top of this screen that collapses when the child of the `RecyclerView` expands. This is intended however when I then scroll on the `RecyclerView`, the collapsed view will suddenly expand to full size.

I assume this is happening because when the child is expanded and the toolbar collapses, it thinks the user has collapsed it on scroll. But because no touch was involved, when I subsequently scroll myself the `RecyclerView` still believes the view was where it was.

Any idea how to either stop the automatic collapsing or get the RecylerView to update with the position of the collapsed view?

Code, if necessary:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytChanges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="89dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                <reroo.reroo.CustomViews.FontText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/itinerary_changes_margin_top"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="Changes:"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#B3ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*EDIT 1:* I have tried adding enterAlways, enterAlwaysCollapsed and exitUntilCollapsed to my xml but I believe this is an issue with the RecyclerView not tracking its position after it has animated with the child expanding.

*EDIT 2:* Using notifyItemChanged(position) after child tap causes the RecyclerView to animate the expansion and collapse, and then subsequently animate the un-collapsing of the view without any user input.

Preferred behaviour: 
animate and collapse. Stay. or
don't animate and collapse, but collapse on scroll

Comment: try adding exitUntilCollapsed or enterAlways in conjunction with scroll

Comment: Same behaviour. I would think this was due to the `RecyclerView` rather than the other views not collapsing correctly.